# How do I embed an Ionic webapp?

Tags: theming, routes

I am building a partially decoupled Drupal 8 site.  Drupal hosts all the content, but I also built mobile apps and a webapp in [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/).  The mobile apps are working fine, and now I want to host the webapp on my Drupal site.

I want my Ionic app to take over all the paths from `/webapp/*`, and these should all redirect to Ionic's `index.html` and then be passed the relevant argument from the URL.

Before I made the Ionic app, I had a React app, which I embedded into Drupal as follows.

This is the code I am using.

#### MY_MODULE/src/Controller/PageController.php

```php
  public function reactApp() {
    return [
      '#markup' => '<div id="my-react-app"></div>',
      '#attached' => [
        'library' => [
          'MY_THEME/react_app',
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }
```

#### MY_MODULE/MY_MODULE.routing.yml

```yaml
MY_MODULE.myreactapp:
  path: '/webapp/{react_route}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\MY_MODULE\Controller\PageController::reactApp'
    _title: 'React App'
  react_route: ''
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

#### MY_THEME.libraries.yml

```yaml
react_app:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/dist/main.min.js: {minified: true}
```

This worked great for embedding a simple react app and giving it all the routes at `/webapp/*`.

However, a webapp built in Ionic generates an index.html that looks like this.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <base href="/"/>
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"/>
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="viewport-fit=cover,width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/icon/favicon.png"/>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Ionic App"/>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>
  <link href="/static/css/4.21302a68.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/static/css/main.1d86f075.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="has-navbar-fixed-top">
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="/static/js/runtime-main.48098029.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/4.54463739.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/main.3b08ecfa.chunk.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### What I want to do

1. Put all the ionic build assets in a subdirectory (`/webapp`) inside my Drupal site (done).
2. Tell Drupal to redirect all requests to (`/webapp`) to Ionic's `index.html`. (how do I do this?)

I thought of using a theme hook, but I don't know how to add all the scripts and css in Ionic's `index.html` to the twig template.

If possible, I don't want to hard-code the Ionic script assets inside Drupal because the names will change every time the app is built, which will be often.

Comment: You shouldn't need any hook at all. Create a folder called webapp. Put a file in it called index.php. Drupal only kicks in when a real file doesn't exist at the given path.

Comment: @Jaypan Yes, that part works.  The problem is the Ionic app has dynamic routes created with React Router-- for example, /webapp/login and /webapp/welcome.  If I go to the index.html page first (the Ionic app) and then navigate from the page, everything is OK.  But, if I try to directly access example.com/webapp/login, then I get Drupal instead of Ionic.  So what I want to know is how can I tell Drupal to redirect me to the Ionic app and give the Ionic app the path it needs to determine which part of the app to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is you have two .htaccess files rewriting URLs to index.php (Drupal) or index.html (Ionic). I think you need to adjust Drupal's rewrite rule because it is in the top level:

```
  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

For example by adding this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webapp
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea.  Unfortunately, my webhost is Pantheon, which uses [Nginx in a stock config](https://pantheon.io/docs/redirects#considerations).

Comment: The link is for redirecting which you are also trying to do in the controller. But then you would only react on traffic which ends up in the wrong index file. Better handle this earlier by stopping rewriting of non-Drupal URLs, which should also be possible to configure in Nginx..

Comment: Alas, Pantheon doesn't allow that either (Pantheon support's solution: upgrade to enterprise and try to configure the CDN to handle it); I'll mark this answer as the accepted one because it covers the general use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hosting with Pantheon, which doesn't allow making changes to the server configuration.  I contacted Pantheon support, who told me that I may be able to do it with domain masking if I upgrade to enterprise hosting.  So I guess I'm stuck with the following until I switch hosts.

Temporary solution: use the PageController to redirect the user to the Ionic app if on the `/webapp/*` path:

In `MY_MODULE/src/Controller/PageController.php`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class PageController extends ControllerBase implements ContainerInjectionInterface {
  public function reactApp($react_route) {
    // Append the react-router route as a query string so I can handle redirects in react.
    $response = new RedirectResponse("/webapp/index.html?&route=$react_route");
    $response->send();
    return;
  }
}
```

In `MY_MODULE/MY_MODULE.routing.yml`:

```
MY_MODULE.myreactapp:
  path: '/webapp/{react_route}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\MY_MODULE\Controller\PageController::reactApp'
    _title: 'React App'
  react_route: ''
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

This will allow the user to use the "back" button when moving from the Ionic app to the Drupal site and then going back.  **However, the user will always be redirected to the index instead of the last page that he/she was actually on, so this is not an ideal solution.**